# Deleted OSX Partition but Wish to Install OSX Again

Tags: macos

A few months ago I installed Windows 10 on my late 2013 iMac without any drivers. Stupidly, I deleted the OSX partition because the only thing that didn't work perfectly was audio, which I was fine with at the time.

I've recently started using Ubuntu on my iMac and audio is back to it's good ol' usual. However, I want to switch back to OSX so I can dual boot between OSX and Ubuntu. How can I reinstall OSX?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hold cmd+r when you turn your mac on to see if it still has a recovery partition or internet recovery (i'm not sure since when internet recovery is available). If it starts in recovery mode, you can re-install os x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OS X Internet Recovery to install the version of OS X that came with your machine. See the Apple web site: [About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). Be sure to hold down the **three** keys at startup: <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. From this, you can go to the App Store and download and install newer versions of OS X.

An alternative would be to use another Mac to download OS X. You can then transfer the download to a USB drive. You then use the USB drive to install OS X on your Mac. The instructions are given the Apple web site: [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

Comment: I would always recommand the second method first. Some (a lot of) people are not in the luxury Internet suburb of the world and don't want to depend on a poor connection or steal the correct connection of their company or their friends.